# About the regex '(\ba\b) \B\1\B'

Tags: regular-expression

This is a follow up to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543742/group-capturing-word-boundaries) question. I think it is sufficiently different that it merits a new question.

As I understand it, capture groups only capture text, this means that when matching `(\ba\b)` only the string `a` is saved, the word boundaries are not included per se, as they aren't text.

This leads me to believe that the pattern `(\ba\b) \B\1\B` should be able to match `a zaz` (after all the second occurrence of `a` is in-betweeen two non-word boundaries), but it doesn't match.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why would `\B` match `z`? Or, what matches `z` there?

Comment: the z's. you're missing the zeds. Please post a complete example if this is just a thinko/typo.

Comment: You might have meant to use `(\ba\b) .\B\1\B.`?  The two `\B` would force the two `.` to match word characters, i.e. the `z`'s in your data.

Comment: Yeah, or just `.*` instead of space. It's quite impossible to suggest a solution as it's completely unclear what this regular expression is supposed to achieve, and you'd never write it this way anyhow. There's no point in `(a) \1` you'd just write `a a`. Maybe this question was oversimplified, show your problems/goals and get better answers or maybe even a completely different solution.

Comment: I'm so sorry, everyone. I'm stupid today. Hopefully my mistake can help someone else in the future.

Comment: @frostschutz My goal is understanding, these are adequate minimally working examples. What isn't adequate is my brain :)

Comment: To make it clearer, I was thinking that `\B` ought to match `z`, which of course it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the z?

```
$ echo a zaz | grep -P '(\ba\b) \B\1\B'
- no output -
$ echo a zaz | grep -P '(\ba\b) z\B\1\Bz'
a zaz
```

Just like `\b` does not include additional characters in the parenthesis, `\B` does not match additional characters either. So there is nothing in the regexp that would allow matching the z's around a.